# Inverse trig expression simplification problem

Tags: trigonometry

Equation: $\sin(2\arctan x)$

And I have to simplify it. I can only go this far, and then I lack ideas:

Let $\arctan x = \alpha$

$$\sin(\alpha+\alpha)=2\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)$$

So I haven't progressed really.

Perhaps I should use $\cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha= 1$, to express $\tan$ as $\mathrm{cosec}$ and then as $\sec$ and insert those into the above. But I have no clue what $\sin(\mathrm{acosec}(x))$ would equal to (or $\cos(\mathrm{arcsec}(x))$).

EDIT: I see now how to express $\sin$ or $\cos$ of an arbitrary angle just in terms of tangent.

$$\tan \mu \equiv \frac{\sin \mu}{\cos \mu}$$
$$\sin \mu \equiv \tan \mu \cos \mu$$
$$\cos \mu \equiv \frac{1}{\sec \mu}$$
$$\tan^2 \mu + 1 \equiv \sec^2 \mu$$ $$\sec \mu \equiv \sqrt{\tan^2 \mu + 1}$$
Therefore, $$\sin \mu \equiv \frac{\tan \mu}{\sqrt{\tan^2 \mu + 1}}$$

Also, there is a nice way of expressing $\sin 2\mu$ in terms of $\tan \mu$ which is extremely useful in this case. It can be found in the answer that I have selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\arctan x=u\implies x=\tan u$

$$\sin(2\arctan x)=\sin2u=\dfrac{2\tan u}{1+\tan^2u}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$\arctan x=\alpha$ means that $ x=\tan \alpha$. So you starting point is correct, simply you have to use the classical formulas:

$$
\sin \alpha= \pm \dfrac{\tan \alpha}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \alpha}}
$$

$$
\cos \alpha= \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 \alpha}}
$$
that becomes:
$$
\sin \alpha= \pm \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$

$$
\cos \alpha= \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\arctan x$ ; we have
$$\sin\left(\arctan x\right)=\sin u=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 u}=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 u}}=\frac{\tan u}{1+\tan^2 u}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$
Similarly, we have
$$\cos\left(\arctan x\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$
Thus,
$$\sin\left(2\arctan x\right)=2\sin\left(\arctan x\right)\cos\left(\arctan x\right)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.$$